# Proper Triage close reason for "write this for me"?

Tags: discussion, triage, minimal-reproducible-example

I like that the text of the "For help with debugging your code..." choice includes the bit about MCVE, which is what is needed for these questions, but the opening doesn't seem right because there is no code.

What is the proper choice for a question which would be good if but for a MCVE?

Comment: Don't spend too much time worrying about the exact close reason that you choose. If you *know* the question needs closing, that's the important part. Pick one that fits reasonably well and get on with your life. Too broad, Unclear, and Off Topic/No MCVE are all reasonable choices for this type of question.

Comment: It rather depends on the tag.  If it is [regex] or [sql] for example then such a question is entirely normal.  If it is a plain task instead of a question then it is simple.  You'll have to use your judgement, press Skip if you are not sure.

Comment: Sorry, I searched but didn't find that one.  Hard topic to search for I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd close such a question as 'too broad':

> There are either **too many possible answers**, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

(emphasis mine)